# Checked items CheckedListBox with Object Collection

Tags: c#, extension-methods, generic-list, generic-collections

I have `checkedlistbox` bind using my generic list. I need to checked the items based on the value. As i am bind using object collection i need to cast the object and check the id. For this i useed the following loop and it is suceeded

```
if (currentDeliveryNote.Quotations != null)
{
      foreach (QuotationBase item in currentDeliveryNote.Quotations)
      {
           for (int i = 0; i < chklstQuotation.Items.Count; i++)
           {
                if (((QuotationBase)chklstQuotation.Items[i]).ID == item.ID)
                {
                     chklstQuotation.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                }
           }
      }
}
```

Now the same concept is for all other pages also. But only the difference is Object name is different. eg: In this page this is `QuotationBase`. For next page this is `DeliveryNote` and Another is `Invoice` etc.

So how i write a generic extension method to checked the items. All object have ID property and it is used to compare with the list for check.

Comment: Do you have any base class for Quotationbase, DeveliveryNote and Invoice and what is type of ID.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put your ID property on an interface and then you can use generics:

```
public static void CheckItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, CheckList checkList) where T : IIdentifiable
{
    if (items != null)
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < checkList.Items.Count; i++)
           {
                if (((T)checkList.Items[i]).ID == item.ID)
                {
                     checkList.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
public interface IIdentifiable
{
    string ID { get; }
}

public class Quotationbase : IIdentifiable
...
```